# Replace Placeholder on text type

Tags: yadcf

I'm wondering if it's possible to replace the placeholder text of an input..

```
yadcf.init(myTable, [
  {column_number : 0, filter_type: "text", case_insensitive: true, filter_container_id: "pokedex-number-filter", filter_reset_button_text: false, style_class: "form-control"},
  {column_number : 1, filter_type: "text",  case_insensitive: true, filter_container_id: "pokemon-name-filter", filter_reset_button_text: false, style_class: "form-control"},
  {column_number : 2, filter_type: "text",  case_insensitive: true, filter_container_id: "pokemon-gen-filter", filter_reset_button_text: false, style_class: "form-control"},
```

]);

Answer (score 1):

You can user the following

```
* setDefaults
                Description:        Set global defaults for all yadcf instances.
                Arguments:          Object consisting of anything defined under "Global Parameters"
                Usage example:      yadcf.setDefaults({'language': {'select': 'تحديد قيمة'}});
```

or you can set per single table, per column using the `filter_default_label` option

read more inside [the yadcf js file](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/4e9b9edee6bb17476dabeeae8ce236f1a203445c/dist/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js)